Согласование падежа с числительным
"помогите спасти 673 хвостиков приюта "щенячий ангел""
Корректен ли падеж выделенного слова? Или при использовании состаных числительных можно использовать ед. число - хвостика - звучит приятнее для слуха.

Это не ед. число, а разные падежи. Именительный с родительным

Правильно:
Помогите спасти 673 хвостика приюта "Щенячий ангел".
Пояснение
При решении задачи надо знать следующие темы:

Особенности числительных два, три, четыре при сочетании с существительными: два (три, четыре) щенка (ед. ч.  Р. п.), но пять (шесть и т. д.) щенков (мн. ч. Р. п.)

Категорию одушевленности могут выражать числительные два, три, четыре и собирательные числительные (двое, трое и т.д.), при этом В. п. числительного выражает форма Р. п.:


Надо спасти три дерева (В. п. для неодуш. сущ.), но трех щенков (форма Р. п. для одуш. сущ.). Обратим внимание на то, что в Р. п. числительное согласуется существительным по падежу.

Составные числительные одушевленность выражать не могут:

Надо спасти 673 щенка, 673 дерева. Для одуш. и неодуш. существительных числовой оборот выглядит одинаково, а именно: числительное три задает существительному форму Р. п. ед.ч.
Сравнить: Надо спасти 675 щенков, 675 деревьев.

Некорректен (если вы говорите "шестьсот семьдесят три хвостика"):
670 хвостиков
671 хвостик
672 хвостика
673 хвостика
674 хвостика
675 хвостиков
676 хвостиков
677 хвостиков
678 хвостиков
679 хвостиков
Но, возможно, вы читаете эту фразу иначе: "шестьсот семьдесят трёх хвостиков". Тогда да, можно и так. Но в таком случае лучше сделать наращение: 673-х хвостиков
